# Execute a PHP method one time

Tags: php, session, php-5.3, php-5.4, php-5.2

I call first time this route where I put in session 0 :

```
public function userCaptcha(){
    $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 0;
}
```

After that I call another method which is executed 2 times by server :

```
 public function index()
 {
    $this->session = $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'];
    error_log(print_r($_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'],true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");
    $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 3;
    return $this->render('template/index.twig');
 }
```

The view is :

```
{{ dump(session) }}
```

In the console for `$_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration']`, I get : `0  3`, In the view only `3`. So the question is, It's possible to send in view value `0` and after that to modify the value of `$_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration']` in 3 ? I repeat that index() method is call 2 times by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this? If I understand you correctly, coz my english is not well

```
private $flag = false;

public function index()
{
    $this->session = $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'];
    error_log(print_r($_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'],true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");

    if ($this->flag) {
        $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 3;
    } else {
        $this->flag = true;
    }

    return $this->render('template/index.twig');
}
```

Also you can pass an additional parameter (I think it will be better):

```
public function index($changeSessionValue = false)
{
    $this->session = $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'];
    error_log(print_r($_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'],true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");

    if ($changeSessionValue) {
        $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 3;
    }

    return $this->render('template/index.twig');
}
```

Comment: Not work, so when I acces route homepage, method index() is called 2 times. Now I want if I access first time homepage(method index() is called 2 times and the value from session need to be 0). If I access second time the route homepage (method index() is executed 2 times and value need to be 3)

Comment: In your case I get only `0 0`

Comment: `<?php
 session_start();

 class Test {
  private $isSecondCall = false;

  public function index()
  {    
      if ($this->isSecondCall) {
          $_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration'] = 3;
      } else {
       $this->isSecondCall = true;
      }

      var_dump($_SESSION['isFacebookRegistration']);
  }
 }

 $a = new  Test;

 $a->index();
 $a->index();`

Is works for me